# All projects with Thread on android tell "unfortunately <app> has stopped working"

Tags: android, multithreading

please some help all projects i write with thread are telling me same thing

just anything with thread gives me problem

please i have a competition to win please quick answers

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    //getActionBar().hide();
    /*start up the splash screen and main menu in a time delayed thread*/
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mainMenu = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SFMainMenu.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainMenu);
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(R.layout.fadein,R.layout.fadeout);
        }
    }, SFEngine.GAME_THREAD_DELAY);
}
```

Comment: Use `Runnable()` instead of `Thread()`. You cannot start a new activity from  a different Thread

Comment: You should also post the logcat that shows the crash happening to make it easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

See the API reference
[public final boolean postDelayed (Runnable r, long delayMillis)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

You should use `Runnable`. Try

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mainMenu = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SFMainMenu.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainMenu);
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(R.layout.fadein,R.layout.fadeout);
        }
    }, SFEngine.GAME_THREAD_DELAY);
```